# Is it possible to centralize the text in the Statusbar?

Tags: text, center, autohotkey, statusbar, centralized

Is it possible to centralize the text in the Statusbar?

**OBS: In The Program Autohotkey**

```
;Simple Example

Gui, Add, StatusBar

SB_SetText("I want that centered text here")

Gui, Show, Center w600 h300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you use tabs, like this:

```
;Simple Example
Gui, Add, StatusBar
SB_SetText(A_Tab "I want that centered text here")
Gui, Show, Center w600 h300
```

One tab for centered text, two tabs for right-aligned text.

See docs for more information: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#SB_SetTextNewText__PartNumber_Style